# How to convert column values to comma separated with alias

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to convert column values to comma separated **with alias** for using this output in dynamic query? `MyTable` table has two columns `DayNo` & `CR_Date` with data:

```
Day1    01/01/2000
Day2    01/02/2002
Day3    05/01/2003
Day4    01/01/1999
Day5    08/01/1998
Day6    01/19/2010
Day7    01/01/2000
Day8    01/01/2011
Day9    12/05/2000
Day10   01/01/2017
```

My attempt:

```
declare @AllRowsInOneRow nvarchar (2000)
set @AllRowsInOneRow = ''

select @AllRowsInOneRow = 
case when @AllRowsInOneRow = ''
then CR_Date
else @AllRowsInOneRow + coalesce(''' as '+Day_No+',''' + CR_Date, '')
end
from MyTable

select @AllRowsInOneRow = 'select ''' + @AllRowsInOneRow + ''''

select @AllRowsInOneRow
```

Output:

```
select '01/01/2000' as Day2,'01/02/2002' as Day3,'05/01/2003' as Day4,
'01/01/1999' as Day5,'08/01/1998' as Day6,'01/19/2010' as Day7,
'01/01/2000' as Day8,'01/01/2011' as Day9,'12/05/2000' as Day10, '01/01/2017'
```

Desired output:

```
select '01/01/2000' as Day1,'01/02/2002' as Day2,'05/01/2003' as Day3,
'01/01/1999' as Day4,'08/01/1998' as Day5,'01/19/2010' as Day6,
'01/01/2000' as Day7,'01/01/2011' as Day8,'12/05/2000' as Day9,
'01/01/2017' as Day10
```

DDL:

```
Create table MyTable (Day_No varchar(5), CR_Date varchar(20))
go
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day1' , '01/01/2000')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day2' , '01/02/2002')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day3' , '05/01/2003')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day4' , '01/01/1999')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day5' , '08/01/1998')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day6' , '01/19/2010')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day7' , '01/01/2000')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day8' , '01/01/2011')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day9' , '12/05/2000')
insert into MyTable values ( 'Day10' , '01/01/2017')
```

Comment: are you talking about pivoting ?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you're adding the column name in the coalesce to the previous column, you should have it in both branches, and at the end of the column

Comment: @YashveerSingh no, it is just close.

Comment: @JamesZ, so is there a alternative solution in you point of view ?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader update my answer with output of my query now I think it matches . Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this   this will give you the desired output .

```
declare @tmp varchar(250)           
SET @tmp = ''
select @tmp = @tmp + ''''+  CR_Date + '''' + ' as '  +Day_No + ', '      from MyTable

select  + 'select ' +  SUBSTRING(@tmp, 0, LEN(@tmp))
```

Output:-

```
select '01/01/2000' as Day1, '01/02/2002' as Day2, 
'05/01/2003' as Day3, '01/01/1999' as Day4,
'08/01/1998' as Day5,   '01/19/2010' as Day6, 
'01/01/2000' as Day7, '01/01/2011' as Day8,
'12/05/2000' as Day9, '01/01/2017' as Day10
```

Comment: The output is this .  01/01/2000 as Day1, 01/02/2002 as Day2, 05/01/2003 as Day3, 01/01/1999 as Day4, 08/01/1998 as Day5, 01/19/2010 as Day6, 01/01/2000 as Day7, 01/01/2011 as Day8, 12/05/2000 as Day9, 01/01/2017 as Day10

Comment: oh select is missing rest the output is correct .Let me update my answer

Comment: and after adding `select` the desired output and your output is not matching

Comment: Thanks a lot for patience  it took few try to get it right  so nice of you . thanks for accepting

Comment: welcome , plz remove @final variable, is it not used.